# How do I listen for TimeSlider Event in ArcMap using C#

Tags: c#, events, time, arcmap, arcobjects

I am updating rows of featureclasses via a plugin using C# and ArcObjects. For some reason the featureclasses then are not refreshing properly when the slider is moved, they do display properly if I manually refresh the map, however. I want to test if forcing a full refresh of the display on timeslider updates will work around the issue. In order to do that I want to listen for timeslider update events in my code.

I have seen another bug related to ArcSDE Direct Connection tables not displaying properly, but this is not my issue as I am not using an ArcSDE Direct Connection.

I have also recomputed attribute indexes (on time field) and spatial indexes but no dice.

So, hoping that refreshing on timeslider updates might help.

My C# plugin is running in ArcMap 10.1 SP1. Background enterprise geoDB is on SQLServer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of searching I posted my question, then found my solution within an hour.

```
ITimeDisplayEvents_DisplayTimeChangedEventHandler DTC_EH;



    private void enableTimeDisplayEventHandler(bool enable = true)
        {

            IMxDocument pMxDoc = ArcMap.Document;
            IMap pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap;
            IActiveView pActiveView = pMap as IActiveView;
            IScreenDisplay pScreenDisplay = pActiveView.ScreenDisplay;
            ITimeDisplay pTimeDisplay = pScreenDisplay as ITimeDisplay;

    DTC_EH = new ITimeDisplayEvents_DisplayTimeChangedEventHandler(this.OnDisplayTimeChangedEventHandler);
                        ((ITimeDisplayEvents_Event)pTimeDisplay).DisplayTimeChanged += DTC_EH;
}


private void OnDisplayTimeChangedEventHandler(IDisplay d, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
{
            IMxDocument pMxDoc = ArcMap.Document;
            IMap pMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap;
            IActiveView pActiveView = pMap as IActiveView;
            pActiveView.Refresh();
}
```

Hopefully somebody else finds that useful.